# qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 5 (BadAtom) error message

Tags: qt, runtime-error

When I run my program written in QT I get this error:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 5 (BadAtom), sequence: 528, resource id: 0, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
```

I won't paste my code here because I don't want to get a solution for this problem. I just want to know what this error means. I found on the internet what errors 2 and 3 mean, but I can't find the meaning of error 5. In GCC, LLVM or any other compiler, compilation errors have clear information. In QT I get "error 5". "BadAtom" doesn't help much.

PS

Could anyone recommend a good QT debugger?